# Convert text to Time format in python

Tags: python, datetime, text, time

I have time values in text as:

```
a="060453"

b="135309"
```

I want to convert the above into **"HH:MM:SS"** format and also get the difference in the same format.

```
13:53:09 - 06:04:53 = 07:49:06
```

Regards

Comment: Did you try something? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: @Plopp regex is entirely overkill when there is a built-in `datetime` module that will handle this just fine, in addition to correctly working out the difference between two timestamps

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your math is right but I think this is kind of what you want:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime.datetime.strptime("135309", "%H%M%S") - datetime.datetime.strptime("060453", "%H%M%S")
7:48:16
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the timedelta you need-

```
from datetime import datetime
a="060453"
b="135309"
a = datetime.strptime(a,'%H%M%S')
b = datetime.strptime(b,'%H%M%S')
print(b-a)
```